# How to extract multiple theme stylesheets with webpack?

Tags: reactjs, sass, webpack

I am trying to make a React app themeable. For now themes only consist of different sets of Sass variables which define different header colors, etc.

From my current understanding the `ExtractTextPlugin` seems to be my best bet as I don't want my styles to be inlined and rather have separate files per theme.

So I created two themes:

```
src/scss/themes/theme-a.scss
src/scss/themes/theme-b.scss
```

The themes import the basic layout and common styles and override the relevant variables.

But the only way I managed to make webpack create separate css files 
for both themes was to create distinct entry points for each theme in
my `webpack.prod.config`:

```
entry: {
  app: './src/js/init.js',
  theme-a: './src/scss/themes/theme-a.scss',
  theme-b: './src/scss/themes/theme-b.scss'
},
```

But adding a new entry point for every new theme that gets added feels wrong and I figure there must be a better way?

Comment: Hm, I believe you need a reference in `plugins`, similar to `new ExtractTextPlugin('css/bundle.css')`. I've not seen folks putting these intro `entry`. I only separate CSS into a single file, but check here, he seems to extract 2 files in the example (be it css and less): https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin#api

Comment: Hm, but adding multiple plugin instances instead of multiple entries doesn't sound much more comfortable. What would be nice if one could tell the plugin that it spits out a separate css file for each scss file it encounters within a certain source/folder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's your solution:

```
npm i --save-dev file-loader
```

In the `loaders` section, add this:

```
{
    test: /themes\/.+\.scss$/,
    loader: "file-loader?name=./compiled-themes/css/[name].css!css!sass"
},
```

There may be more scss files, if so there must be another section which bundles them as usual, but skips the themes:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /themes\/.+\.scss$/,
    loader: "css!sass"
},
```

The file loader writes files by filename, hash and extension so you are able to preserve the name.

Note the `name=./compiled-themes/css/[name].css` part, where `[]` vars are substituted.

https://github.com/webpack/file-loader

Comment: to clarify, file-loader is in fact a file writer, but it has this -loader suffix as per the webpack plugin naming convention

Comment: This looks like a really nice solution!

I tried to adapt your example and the compiled themes are created. Great!

But somehow the files don't consist of pure css but are wrapped in a module

`exports = module.exports = require("./../../../node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js")();`
`// imports`
`// module`
`exports.push([module.id, ".ReactModal__Overlay{z-index:999;overflow:auto;margin:0!important;padding:0...`

Do you have an idea what might be the issue?
My loader line for the themes looks like this:

`loader: "file-loader?name=./compiled-themes/css/[name].css!css!sass"`

Comment: `raw!saas` would do the trick. I just tried it. You need to `npm i raw-loader`

Comment: Ah! Somehow I didn't even need the raw-loader. I just had to omit the css-loader.

Comment: Is there a way to get this working properly? If i use the suggested setup, I get the JS otuput in the css like Tudor shows above. I can't take out the css-loader because then my url's in the CSS are output incorrectly.

Comment: Can you please show me the context of a sass file that you are using

Answer (score 3):

To avoid having to manually add the themes one possible solution is to create a function that reads contents of the themes folder and programatically add an entry for each *.scss file.

Something along the lines of this:

```
function getThemes(themePath) {
    var themes = {};
    fs.readdirSync(themePath).forEach(function(fileName) {
        var fileNameWithPath = path.join(themePath, fileName);

        var stat = fs.lstatSync(fileNameWithPath);
        if (stat.isDirectory()) return;
        if (!/\.scss$/.test(fileName)) return;

        var nameWithoutExt = path.basename(fileName, '.scss');
        themes[nameWithoutExt] = fileNameWithPath;
    });

    return themes;
}

var themes = getThemes('./src/scss/themes');

var config= {
    entry: _.merge({ app: './src/js/init.js' }, themes),
    // rest of options
};
```

This will require you to restart your dev-server or re-run you webpack build when adding new theme files though, but at least you won't have to touch your webpack config.

Comment: This setup seems to result in a JS file being output for every CSS file aswell as the CSS file itself. Is there any way to stop the JS file from being output?